# Trying to debug PHP Seg Feault

Tags: php, c, gdb

I am trying to debug a PHP extension that is seg faulting using gdb but I seem to be running into some issues with debugging. When I run gdb with php on I get the following

```
#0  0x00007fff8eb6e732 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fff5fbfe910 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000100ebe21b in ?? ()
#3  0xffff0000ffff027f in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000ffffffff in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

And it doesn't seem to be helping much, because it is empty. Am I missing something (the `??` and `()`) so I can figure out what part is seg faulting?

Comment: The "?? ()" means that it doesn't know the function name at the hexadecimal address listed to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that `php` and your `php` extension is compiled with symbolic output (i.e. using the `-g` flag and not passed to `strip`). Depending on your distribution, the distribution may have an alternate version.

However, that stack trace looks suspicious. It looks to me like something has overwritten the stack.